# Ignore wildcard in MSSQL Variable?

Tags: sql, sql-server, wildcard

I have a stored procedure which includes two parameters. Prefix varchar(50) and Suffix varchar(50). The stored procedure selects some rows with a where clausle. the problem is now, if there is a wildcard in the variable i get something wrong. How do i ignore variable characters which could also be wildcards?

Example:

Lets say i have two rows:

1 . myColumn : 'ABCTTAX'
   2. myColumn: 'ABCTT_X'

```
declare @Prefix varchar(50)
declare @Suffix varchar(50)

set @Prefix = 'ABC';
set @Suffix = '_X';

Select * from myTable where @Suffix IS NOT NULL AND myColumn like @Prefix + '__' + @Suffix
```

In the example above, both rows will match. but i want only the second one to match.

Comment: `set @Suffix = '[_]X';`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Escape the underscore literal by replacing it with brackets.

```
Select * from myTable where @Suffix IS NOT NULL AND myColumn 
    like REPLACE(@Prefix, '_', '[_]') + '__' + REPLACE(@Suffix, '_', '[_]')
```

This patch won't allow prefixes and suffixes to input wildcard underscores.

Comment: And if i want to ignore all wildcards? is there no easyer way then creating a big list of replacements?

Comment: Yep, realised why, mental blip. Double your replaces: `REPLACE(REPLACE(@Suffix, '_', '[_]'),'*','[*])`

Comment: @Amsel if you use the LIKE operator, then you will have to escape all special pattern characters: `[]%_^` (there might be more I'm missing). An alternative to LIKE if you just validate prefixes and suffixes would be using CHARINDEX and comparing against the position of the result.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can do something like,
Try

```
Select * from myTable where @Suffix IS NOT NULL AND myColumn like @Prefix + '%\' + @Suffix escape '\'
```